# Django Pagination Error Handling

Tags: python, django

I am beginner to Django and Python. I am trying to create a simple blog for my learning. I want to make sure when the database is not reachable then the webpage shows 404 template. Below is my views.py file but I am keep getting 500 template.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import Http404
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from blog.models import Post, About

def index(request):
global posts
try:
    all_blog_posts = Post.objects.all()
    published_blog_posts = all_blog_posts.filter(published=True)
except Post.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404('No Posts.')

paginator = Paginator(published_blog_posts, 1)

page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    posts = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    posts = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

try:
    about = About.objects.get(id=1)
except About.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404('No About.')

context = {'posts': posts, 'about': about}
return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context)
```

If I turn the debugging on then I get the ProgrammingError with following exception value,

```
relation "blog_post" does not exist
LINE 1: ...post"."post_author", "blog_post"."published" FROM "blog_post...
```

I think the pagination is trying to run raw query on the database but cannot find the table as database is unreachable. I may be wrong here.

My models.py is,

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
post_title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
post_body = models.TextField()
post_author = models.CharField(max_length=16)
published = models.BooleanField()

class About(models.Model):
summary = models.TextField()
github_url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
twitter_url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
linkedin_url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

My urls.py is

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from blog import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

The app name is blog. I am using Django 1.8 and Python 2.7.6. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create the database.
You need to run:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

to sync your db and create the tables

Look the documentation regarding this command: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate

It's not consistent to throw 404 if the database was not created, but if you really want to do that you can catch any exception, instead of catching only DoesnotExist, but I don't recommend to do that:

```
try:
    all_blog_posts = Post.objects.all()
    published_blog_posts = all_blog_posts.filter(published=True)
except:
    raise Http404('No Posts.')
```

There's this code that you can base your on to throw 404 even if the database wasn't created at all: https://gist.github.com/rctay/527113

Comment: I want the website to throw 404 even if the database does not exist at all. That's why I didn't create the database.

Comment: It's not consistent with the standards of HTTP, that explicit says that 404 means a page not found: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

But if you want to do that anyway, you can simply catch any exception (not only DoesnotExist) and throw the 404

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is a highly unlikely scenario with django as database migration is part of the "usual deployment stack".

But if this is something you are really set on doing, it can be done (although it is not a beginner-level task).
What you want to do is create a Custom Middleware (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception) that will look for ProgrammingError and RegEx match the message (as there can be other ProgrammingError's).
The Middleware should return an HttpResponseNotFound (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseNotFound)

Once your Middleware is ready, add it to your `settings.py` in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware). You will probably want to put it at the very bottom of the list since MiddleWare are executed in reverse order when it comes to exception handling [image](Picture from http://irisbeta.com/article/245366784/the-django-request-response-cycle/?ref&page=user&option=1048576&sort=recent&pageNum=1)

Have fun!